# Provide check in RHS for existence of a field inside pojo in drools

Tags: drools

I am new to drools.
I want to check in RHS that if a field is present in POJO or not.

```
 {
  "category": [
    {
      "nlp": [
        {
          "mainCategory": "Politics"
        }
      ],
      "crawler": [
        {
          "isNLP": true,
          "mainCategory": "Politics"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is list of the pojo that are generated

1. EsRootDoc.java
2. Crawler.java
3. Nlp.java

EsRootDoc is the main class which have methods and fields.`when

```
    $RHSmap1:EsRootDoc()
    and

    $map1:EsRootDoc($categorylist1:category)

    $category2:Category($nlplist2:nlp) from $categorylist1

    $nlp2:Nlp(mainCategory=="politics") from $nlplist2



then

    $RHSmap1.setEvent("fight");

end`
```

This is giving me following error

> [Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: com.orkash.EnrichmentService.EnrichmentController.tempJsonToClass.EsRootDoc.setEvent(java.lang.String)]
>   [Near : {... $RHSmap1.setEvent("fight"); ....}]

I need to provide a check in RHS :- that if **EsRootDoc** has a field **event** or not

Comment: The RHS of the rules is strongly typed. Does your `EsRootDoc` class have a `setEvent(String)` method or not?

Comment: No it doesn't have this method.My use case is that i need to provide a check before calling the setter method that if EsRootDoc have event field then only it should call **setEvent(String)** method

Comment: And how would you do that in plain Java? How does your `EsRootDocument` class looks like? I assume that there are certain subclasses of it that have this method and some others that don't. Right?

Comment: If you are dynamically generating the rules and the classes, then you can use reflection to check whether the setter exists and also to invoke it.

Comment: No actually EsRootDoc have field **category** and 
Category is another class that have fields **nlp** and **crawler**.
Nlp is another class that has mainCategory
I am dynamically generating classes but i want that rules should be generated statically.
So i wanted to provide a check in drl so that if there is **event** in EsRootDoc,
Is there any way of saving contents in drool variable and then checking that if event is present then only setter method would be called

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Drools (as far as I know) that allows you to do what you are looking for. The RHS of a rule is - almost- pure Java. The basic rule then is: if it can't be done in Java, it can't be done in the RHS of  a rule in Drools.

The good news is that what you are trying to do can be achieved in Java using reflection. My recommendation would be for you to create a helper class that uses reflection to set the value of an attribute in an object if that attribute exists. Your rules then would look like this:

```
rule 'Some Rule'
when
    $RHSmap1:EsRootDoc()
    $map1:EsRootDoc($categorylist1:category)
    $category2:Category($nlplist2:nlp) from $categorylist1
    $nlp2:Nlp(mainCategory=="politics") from $nlplist2
then
    Helper.setAttribute($RHSmap1, "event", "fight");
end
```

Hope it helps,